# How to view value of long strings using NetBeans and x-debug?

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

Is there a setting for x-debug or NetBeans to extend the maximum string size it will display?

Using NetBeans to debug PHP application in Windows, I can add a watch or hover over any variable to see its value.  But for long strings, all I get is (string), no value.

Environment:
Windows 7, NetBeans 7.0.1, x-debug 2.0.3-5.1.7, Apache 2.0.63, PHP 5.1.6

php.ini contains:

```
zend_extension_ts = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.1.6\ext\php_xdebug-2.0.3-5.1.7.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.var_display_max_data=2048
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting xdebug.var_display_max_data to -1 seems to have fixed the problem.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Even if your string limits are OK in xdebug, you can still have problems in netbeans.

For this goto to `Options -> PHP -> Debugging` tab in netbeans and set `Maximum Data Length` to a large number like 100000 (I think -1 should also work here).

(Tip from https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=215728#c6 )

Comment: Setting Maximum Data Length to a large number worked. Setting it to -1 caused an error in Xdebug.

Answer (score 2):

Modify [`xdebug.var_display_max_data`](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#var_display_max_data). The default value is `512`, so bump that up to your desired length.

Comment: Thanks alex, but I tried that.  Testing with a string of about 1850 bytes - I originally had xdebug.var_display_max_data=2048 and have since bumped it up to 8192, but still can't see the variable value.

Comment: @AlienTechnology Weird, not sure if I know the answer then.