# decoding $str= imap_fetchbody: $str ==="" but print_r can print it

Tags: php, imap

I have forwarded a html message with pdf attachment from Thunderbird.
I receive multipart/mixed with multipart/alternative containing html and txt-plain, and the pdf base 64 encoded. The multipart/alternative is 8 bit, charset= UTF8.

I have tried nearly all proposals from comments on the imap:fetchstructure/fetchbody manual page on php.net. They include decoding (at least for encoding = 1, 3, 4), applying imap_8bit, imap_qprint and imap_base64. Looking manually at the txt/plain shows encoding = 1, so the imap_8bit is applied.

The example functions can't even decide whether the returned text is plain or html because in all cases, because the returned $str always is === "" (empty string).

next, I accidentally tried a print_r($str) (if imap_8bit is not done), and that has the required email text.
I thought this might be multibyte without imap_8bit and mb_detect_encoding returns UTF8 (just as I can see in the raw email text).

Trying mb_convert_encoding($str, "ASCII") again returns an empty string.
quoted_printable_decode doesn't help either neither before nor after imap_8bit.
netbeans PHP debugger (xdebug) declares all these strings to be empty but announces the variables are 'string'.

Does anybody have an idea how to get to the email text? print_r shows that it is there, but I am banging my head against a wall for days now without any result.

I could manually search and decode the boundaries etc., which wouldn't be toooo difficult, but ... why reinvent the wheel?

Code: primarily, I used two versions from the php.net fetch_structure page and othe r web ressources. I can add them to this post but don't want to blow it up too much at this moment.

*getTxtBody which calls get_part
*getmesg which calls getpart

If I look at the plain text, I clearly see the (nested) boundaries for plain, html and pdf.

any help is very much appreciated., Klaus

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [fetch library](https://github.com/tedivm/Fetch).

To decode headers you can use [iconv_mime_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-decode.php)

Comment: many thanks ...  tried that, but it shows the same behaviour as imap_fetchbody:  if $email contains my fetched email from florish, then the attributes text and html are 'empty' - the netbeans debugger just shows string on mouseover. But print_r($email) shows everything is there . Encoded unreadable?? What can I do? If necessary, I can post the original email as Thunderbird would export it (plain text with all boundaries etc... but long). Any help is appreciated.  Klaus

Comment: Please post the content of mime/eml file.

Comment: this seems to be a strange netbeans debugger problem. If I singlestep through the flourish parsing routine, my string is displayed in the debugger. If I run through all code, the debugger only displays 'string'. var:dump shows the string. substring can get parts of the string, which the debugger displays. Actually, the same for the imap_fetchbody, I can access the string e.g. with substring, but cannot display it in the IDE. Anyway, the primary problem seems solved - my string is decoded, and I can process it. This really took many days .... oh well.... in any case many thanks for your answer

Comment: well, obviously, everything has been asked somewhere before - one only needs the right question. How to display long strings in netbeans: ask stackoverflow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639530/how-to-view-value-of-long-strings-using-netbeans-and-x-debug.  Why does netbeans show the string on single stepping through code, but not when stepping over to a breakpoint ... oh well

Comment: No need to thank, I didn't answer your question. You did good job yourself. :)